# Why is my detoured code, crashing with a NOP

Tags: c++, assembly, crash, hook, detours

Hi this is my first question so please treat me gently.I am detouring an exe, using MS detours and Visual Studio 2005, my dll gets loaded and my hook works a treat however when I try to extend my hook code something is going wrong and the whole thing crashes, I think its creating an exception in the exe which is popping up a message box contact support.

```
typedef void (__stdcall* GenterateStrings)(int,int,int);

GenterateStrings Real_GenterateStrings = (GenterateStrings)(0x06EDFA0);

extern "C" { static void __stdcall myGenterateStrings(int,int,int); }

void __stdcall myGenterateStrings(int a1, int a2, int a3) 
{   
    myLogMessage(L"its working");
    Real_GenterateStrings( a1,  a2,  a3);
    return;
}
```

That works a treat no exceptions and my log file fills with "its working", however, i need to capture EAX after my Real_GenterateStrings() call  as it contains a pointer to a unicode string.

but if i put any code after the Real_GenterateStrings call just cause the crash as soon as its hooked. Even just a nop

```
void __stdcall PokerAdvisorGenterateStrings(int a1, int a2, int a3) 
{   
    myLogMessage(L"its working");
    Real_GenterateStrings( a1,  a2,  a3);
    __asm   
    {
        nop
    }   
    return;
}
```

Any ideas?

The function i am hooking is

```
mov     eax, [rsp+0Ch]
mov     ecx, [rsp+8]
mov     edx, cs:113650Ah
push    rax
mov     eax, [rsp+8]
push    rcx
push    rdx
push    0A3CA2Ch
push    rax
call      near ptr unk_6AB8E0
add     esp, 14h
retn
```

I dont think it returns a value?

Comment: For a minute there, I thought the argument for '__asm' had to be a string. Then I realized that Windows inline assembly, is completely different from GCC's. So I deleted my answer. I can't see anything glaringly wrong with your code.

Comment: Run it with the debugger and get a stack trace, the contents of the registers and find out exactly what is failing.

Comment: I seriously doubt that disassembly is correct, it looks like 32-bit assembler with random 64-bit register names thrown in. Also: it looks like the function is using `__cdecl` as its calling convention. Are you sure it's supposed to be `__stdcall`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you know there is something in `eax` ?

In general, detour crashes are often due to an inaccurate calling convention and/or prototype. I suspect that the detoured function returns a void* or something else. You need to capture the return value and pass it along to the caller once you're done, like so:

```
typedef void* (__stdcall* GenterateStrings)(int,int,int);

GenterateStrings Real_GenterateStrings = (GenterateStrings)(0x06EDFA0);

extern "C" { static void __stdcall myGenterateStrings(int,int,int); }

void* __stdcall myGenterateStrings(int a1, int a2, int a3) 
{   
    myLogMessage(L"its working");
    void* ret = Real_GenterateStrings( a1,  a2,  a3);
    __asm   
    {
        nop
    }   

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I spent 4 days going through the exe with IDA pro to come to the function call i want to detour and eax containing the pointer i need. I have edited my question to show the assembly function, however the changes you suggested, still fail.

Comment: FIXED

i changed __stdcall to __cdecl and bingo

Comment: @Mike: not sure what your point was. the prototype in the question did not have any return value. That's why I asked how it was known something was in eax. I was guessing (wrong) that the compiler was overriding the eax register because of the asm block. @lnfromthecold: I'm glad you found it. As you may note from the disasm, the function you're detouring does not clean its stack parameters. So it wasn't stdcall for sure. But, as Mike mentions, eax is the return value (for all conventions, too). here, the return value is the one of the `call near ptr unk_6AB8E0`